# $P(x)$ doesn't have a rational root?

Tags: polynomials, roots, rational-numbers

Let $P(x)$ be a polynomial with integer coefficients. In what conditions that $P(x)$ doesn't have a rational root?

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem, if $P(x)=a_nx^n+\cdots +a_0$ with integer coefficients, where $a_0\ne 0$, $a_n\ne 0$, then the only conceivable rational roots of $P(x)$ are of the form $\dfrac{a}{b}$, where $a|a_0$, $b|a_n$. However there are some cases that for $a|a_0$, $b|a_n$, $\dfrac{a}{b}$ migh not be a root of $P(x)$.

Are there any general criterion so that $P(x)$ doesn't have a rational root?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem

Comment: What are you hoping for here?  The [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) gives you a good way to test a given polynomial.  Note:  this has little to do with combinatorics or number theory.

Comment: @lulu It has *much* to do with number theory.

Answer (score 2):

In general, if we have a polynomial $P(x)$ with integer coefficients, where $P(x)=a_0x^n+\cdots +a_n$, where $a_0\ne 0$, $a_n\ne 0$, then the only conceivable rational roots of $P(x)$ are of the form $\dfrac{a}{b}$, where $a$ is a divisor (possibly negative) of $a_n$ and $b$ is a positive divisor of $a_0$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I want to know when $P(x)$ doesn't have a rational root. If $a|a_n$ and $b|a_0$, $\frac{a}{b}$ might not be a root of $P(x)$

Comment: I think the recurring answer to your question is rational root theorem, because it's an easy way to check if a polynomial has a rational root. Therefore it's an easy way to check if a polynomial does not have a rational root. Other than that, I don't know any of the top of my head and if I think of one I'll post it here